What tests/analysis should I use to assess if the employees' training time is efficient /enough against their production metrics?
I am working on a case study on customer service industry.
I was tasked to create a case study with a goal of providing potential training curriculum focus to help decrease their current 30-day training curriculum.
These are the data that I have:

Training time per topic
Production Metrics (Call handle time, CSAT scores, Quality scores)

What analysis/methods/test should I use?

Greetings and welcome to CV! I think I missed the purpose a bit here. Do you mean that you want to see if different topics require different hours of training? Or if the amount of training on a given topic produces increases/decreases in the production metrics? Or is there a different goal in mind? It seemed a bit vague here.

Hi @ShawnHemelstrand - we want to see if different topics require different hours of training. And how we can reduce the training time for the current curriculum that they have. Appreciate your response on this one.

Probably the most challenging aspect of this deciding how you defined somebody as being "trained", in other words, what is the stop point that determines someone is at 20 hours? Are people graded in some way on this? Your other goal of designing ways to reduce this will take some more consideration, perhaps doing a survival analysis on different predictors of training time and how they differ by topic.
